# getting jquery cell data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

HI i am using the following code to get the specific column , But i want to give my own rowIndex or initialize rowIndex=2,3 or what ever my row number,  to get the column value how to do it

```
var cellIndexMapping = { 0: true, 2: true };
var data = [];

$("#MyTable tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    $(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex])
            data.push($(this).text());
    });
});

$("#Console").html(data.join("<br />"));
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting an element by index you can use `.eq(index)`, and for slicing the collection you can use `.slice(start, end)` method:

```
var cellIndexMapping = [0, 2];

var data = $("#MyTable tr").slice(2, 4).find('td').map(function(i) {
    return $.inArray(i, cellIndexMapping) > -1 
           ? $(this).text() 
           : null;
}).get();
```

If you don't want to slice the collection, you can `.filter()` the elements:

```
var rowIndexes = [0, 3, 5, 1];

$("#MyTable tr").filter(function(i) {
    return $.inArray(i, rowIndexes) > -1; 
}).foo();
```

Comment: can it do like this
var rowIndex=2;
and pass the rowIndex in my code

Comment: Yes, `$("#MyTable tr").eq(rowIndex).find('td').map()`, I recommend using the `.filter()` method and an array, it works for one and n number of indexes.

Comment: @ozil My first comment is an example, just replace the `.slice(2, 4)` with `.eq(rowIndex)`!